# How to autoload a custom group?

Tags: minor-mode, use-package, autoload

I put my custom js setting into zwb-js group in zwb-js.el, I want to use **use-package** to load it, it seems that zwb-js.el has been loaded, but the functions defined in zwb-js.el seems not be called auto.

This is my code:

```
;;; zwb-js.el --- ZWB Js configuration entry point.

;;; Commentary:

;; This file simply sets up the default load path and requires
;; the various modules defined within Emacs Prelude.

;;; Code:

(defgroup zwb-js nil
  "zwb's js setting."
  :group 'languages
  :prefix "zwb-js-")

(defcustom zwb-js-packages
  '(
    coffee-mode
    company
    company-tern
    flycheck
    js-doc
    js2-mode
    js2-refactor
    json-mode
    json-snatcher
    tern
    web-beautify
    )
  "The package zwb-js needs."
  :type 'alist
  :group 'zwb-js)

;;;###autoload
(defun zwb-js/init-package ()
  (message "debug")
  (prelude-require-packages zwb-js-packages))

(defun zwb-js/post-init-company ()
  (zwb|add-company-hook js2-mode))

(defun zwb-js/post-init-flycheck ()
  (add-hook 'js2-mode-hook  'flycheck-mode)
  (add-hook 'json-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)
  (defun zwb|disable-js2-checks-if-flycheck-active ()
    (unless (flycheck-get-checker-for-buffer)
      (set (make-local-variable 'js2-mode-show-parse-errors) t)
      (set (make-local-variable 'js2-mode-show-strict-warnings) t)))
  (add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'zwb|disable-js2-checks-if-flycheck-active))

(defun zwb-js/post-init-tern ()
  (add-hook 'js-mode-hook (lambda () (tern-mode t)))
  (add-to-list 'company-backends '(company-tern :with company-dabbrev-code)))

(defun zwb-js/init-js-doc ()
  (defun zwb-js/js-doc-require ()
    (require 'js-doc))
  (add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'zwb-js/js-doc-require))

(defun zwb-js/init-js2-refactor ()
  (defun zwb-js/js2-refactor-require ()
    (require 'js2-refactor))
  (add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'zwb-js/js2-refactor-require))

(defun zwb-js/init-js-color ()
  (setq js2-highlight-level 3)
  (defun zwb-js/rainbow-delimiters-require ()
    (require 'rainbow-delimiters)
    (rainbow-delimiters-mode))
  (dolist (hook '(js2-mode-hook js-mode-hook json-mode-hook))
    (add-hook hook 'zwb-js/rainbow-delimiters-require)))

(defun zwb-js/node-repl ()
  (setq inferior-js-program-command "node")
  (setenv "NODE_NO_READLINE" "1")
  (setq inferior-js-mode-hook (lambda () (ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)))
  (defun zwb-js/comint-key-binding ()
    (local-set-key (kbd "C-x C-e") 'js-send-last-sexp)
    (local-set-key (kbd "C-M-x") 'js-send-last-sexp-and-go)
    (local-set-key (kbd "C-c b") 'js-send-buffer)
    (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-b") 'js-send-buffer-and-go)
    (local-set-key (kbd "C-c l") 'js-load-file-and-go))
  (add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'zwb-js/comint-key-binding))

(defun zwb-js/conf-js2-mode ()
  "Conf js2-mode and so on."
    (custom-set-variables
     '(js2-basic-offset 2)
     '(js2-bounce-indent-p nil))

    (setq-default js2-mode-show-parse-errors nil)
    (setq-default js2-mode-show-strict-warnings nil)

    (setq json-reformat:indent-width 2))

(defun zwb-js/js-fontlock ()
  (defvar js-font-lock-keywords
    `(("\\(function *\\)[(|[[:space:]]]?"
       (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                 (match-end 1) "\u0192")
                 nil)))
      ("[[:space:]]\\(var\\)[[:space:]]"
       (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                 (match-end 1) "\u028b ")
                 nil)))
      ("[[:space:]]\\(return\\)[[:space:]]"
       (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                 (match-end 1) "\u1d3f ")
                 nil)))
      ("\\(this\\)"
       (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                 (match-end 1) "\u0288")
                 nil)))))
  (eval-after-load 'js
    (font-lock-add-keywords
     'js2-mode js-font-lock-keywords)))

(provide 'zwb-js)
;;; zwb-js.el ends here
```

I can use **C-h v** config **zwb-js-packages**, so I don't know why I cann't see any defuns with M-x.

I also wrote zwb-js-autoloads.el to autoload **zwb-js/init-package** for test, but it seems not work.

This is my zwb-js-autoloads.el:

```
;;; zwb-js-autoloads.el --- automatically extracted autoloads
;;
;;; Code:
(add-to-list 'load-path (or (file-name-directory #$) (car load-path)))

;;;### (autoloads nil nil ("zwb-js.el"))

(provide 'zwb-js-autoloads)
;;;***

;; Local Variables:
;; version-control: never
;; no-byte-compile: t
;; no-update-autoloads: t
;; End:
;;; zwb-js-autoloads.el ends here
```

I also tried:

```
;;; zwb-js-autoloads.el --- automatically extracted autoloads
;;
;;; Code:
(add-to-list 'load-path (or (file-name-directory #$) (car load-path)))

(autoload 'zwb-js/init-package "zwb-js" "\
Install all packages that zwb-js needs
\(fn)" nil nil)

(provide 'zwb-js-autoloads)
;;;***

;; Local Variables:
;; version-control: never
;; no-byte-compile: t
;; no-update-autoloads: t
;; End:
;;; zwb-js-autoloads.el ends here
```

Loaded by personal/load-private-config.el:

```
(defconst zwb-private-emacs-config-path "~/.emacs.d-private/")

(eval-and-compile
  (mapc
   #'(lambda (path)
       (push (expand-file-name path zwb-private-emacs-config-path) load-path))
   '("lib""theme" "")))

(eval-and-compile
  (defvar use-package-verbose t)
  (require 'cl)
  (require 'use-package))

(use-package zwb-js
  :defer t  ;; I tried commit or uncommit it
  :load-path (lambda () (expand-file-name (concat zwb-private-emacs-config-path "lib/zwb-js")))
  :init (require 'zwb-js-autoloads))
```

Both of the way, I cann't get **debug** in ***Message*** buffer, which defined in zwb-js/init-package for test.

My questions are:

1. Why I cann't see my defuns through M-x?
2. What's the best way to use **use-package** to load zwb-js?
3. How to autoload my zwb-js group?
4. How to auto run all defun defined in zwb-js?
5. What's defgroup's prefix used for? Would you please give me an example?

My OS version: **Mac OS X 10.11.2 beta4**
My Emacs version: **24.5.1 (brew emacs-mac-emacs)**
My Emacs config is based on **Prelude**